# Karate API Tests - Escaping '?' in the url in a feature file

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java, karate

I am using the ***path*** keyword from Karate API framework to concatenate strings to form a url. However, I am not able to pass '?'. Here is what I am doing:

```
 Background: 
    * url 'https://api.cloud.abcde.com/animal/'

 Scenario: Verify the get status
    Given path 'herbivore?id=25'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

When I run the test, i see the '?' being passed as %3F. I tried to escape it using \ and tried some other answers too but couldn't succeed. Do I need to use url encoding ? Any pointers or help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried a double backslash \\...

Comment: @Grasshopper -it didnt work in the karate framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `param` for this case:

```
Scenario: Verify the get status
    Given path 'herbivore'
    And param id = 25
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

Comment: I am getting error Step param id doesn't have a matching glue code.

Comment: @Saurabh there must be some other problem. Here is an example you can refer to: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/greeting/greeting.feature

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Comment: If you are having @Saurabh's error remember to leave spaces between your query param name, the equality operator and the value. E.g. id=25 will fail. id = 25 is the right way.